# Use a for-loop to create a new DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am working on the Cars.csv DataFrame which can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/ljanjughazyan/cars1

My goal is to create a new Data Frame with the column names: USA, Europe and Japan and to save the number of cars that are in each category.

```
for a in list(cars.origin.unique()):
    x= pd.DataFrame({a:[cars.loc[cars["origin"]==a,"origin"].size]})
```

I tried it with this code, but as a result I obtain a Data Frame with only one column that is "Europe". So it kind of works, but I cant figure why it just dismisses the other values. Why doesnt it work and can it be done using a for-loop?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume "Europe" would be the last item in your list. Because you are resetting x in every iteration of your for-loop.

So if you `print(x)` inside the loop, you should first see a DataFrame with just USA, then just Japan and then just Europe, which is your final result.

I would suggest putting the data into a python `dict` and creating you DataFrame afterwards.

```
data = {}
for a in list(cars.origin.unique()):
    data[a] = [cars.loc[cars["origin"]==a,"origin"].size]
x = pd.DataFrame(data)
```